# Find missing and overlapping numbers in sequences

Tags: c#, linq, range, sequence

Let's say we have a data structure like this:

```
var sequences = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
                {
                    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 10),
                    new Tuple<int, int>(8, 101),
                    new Tuple<int, int>(102, 103),
                    new Tuple<int, int>(104, 104),
                    new Tuple<int, int>(110, 200)
                };
```

I would like to get two results from this collection:

- All the missing numbers (in this example: 105, 106, 107, 108, 109)
- All the overlapping numbers (in this example: 8, 9, 10)

I could write an algorithm with a couple of loops and helper collections. This off course would work, but I wonder if this could be achieved with the help of LINQ and/or other easier and shorter algorithms?

Edit: 
My data structure from the example above is representing 5 sequences, the first one containing numbers from 1 to 10, the second one containing the numbers from 8 to 101 and so on... Because in the production the sequences can be much bigger (up to millions), they are not represented with the actual collection (for instance with Lists with all the numbers), but with Tuples, which represents the minimal and the maximal number of each sequence.

Comment: I do not understand why you call 8, 9 and 10 "overlapping numbers". I do not understand why you call 105, 106, 107, 108, 109 missing numbers. -1

Comment: The series is not continuous - missing number

Comment: @Matt Ellen: The numbers in the tuples represent the first and last number in a sequence, so the sequence `1..10` overlaps the sequence `8..101`, and there is a gap between the sequences `104..104` and `110..120`.

Comment: @Matt Ellen Д: I would assume that the first and second numbers of each tuple represent the lower and upper bounds of an inclusive range of numbers. 8, 9, and 10 are "overlapping" because they're included in both the first range (1 to 10) and the second range (8 to 101). 105, 106, 107, 108, and 109 are "missing" because they're not included in any range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it via

```
var missing = 
      Enumerable.Range(1, 200)
               .Where(i => sequences.All(t => t.Item1 > i || t.Item2 < i));
var overlapping = 
      Enumerable.Range(1, 200)
                .Where(i => sequences.Count(t => t.Item1 <= i && t.Item2 >= i) > 1);
```

Comment: Beautiful - just what I was looking for :)

Comment: but you need to know the lower and upper bounds of the sequence ranges

Comment: Hm... fails for: var list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
                           {
                               new Tuple<int, int>(-1000, 0),
                               new Tuple<int, int>(10, 1000)
                           }; Yes, I have set the lower and upper bounds to correct values (-1000, 1000). The list of missing values is empty.

Comment: and it will iterate the entire list of tuples twice for each possible value or (2*)N*M where N is the number of possible values and M the number of tuples. With millions of possible values I'll say that's a lot of iterations!

Comment: @sven: You'd need to use `Enumerable.Range(-1000, 2000)`. The first one is the first number, the second is the number of items (not the last)

Comment: @Rune: You are right, of course. If this section is performance critical, or the list of sequences gets large, this might not be a good way to do it. To me its more readable than the other options presented, so I'd use it until the performance bit me. =)

Comment: @Dean Chalk: You'd have to know these anyhow, unless you assume that the first and last items in your range are never missing.

Comment: It works, I used your approach. Will refactor it if nessesary, probably with Rune FS's help :)

Comment: @Jens "Because in the production the sequences can be much bigger (up to millions)" I read that as "We've already optimized because our collections are huge" hence the focus on performance. Seeing that this is the accepted answer I guess we can conclude it's not as important as the statement made me believe. I like the clarity of your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I know algorithm for this problem (it is pseudoCode). ( Complexity classes `O(nlog(n))` where n is count of tuple)

So solution is sort Tuple by function:

```
  int comparer( Tuple a, Tuple b) {
      if ( a.first.compareTo(b.first) == 0 ) {
          return a.second.compareTo(b.second);
      } else 
          return a.first.compareTo(b.first);
  }
```

so example tuple: (1, 10), (1, 5), (2, 8) will be sort to:
(1,5), (1, 10), (2, 8).

Next step is accumulate this result. Iterate on this result and :

```
 Tuple result = SortedList[0];
 foreach ( Tuple tuple in SortedList ) {

     if ( result.second < tuple.first ) {

        // here you have missing number (result.second, tuple.first)

        result.first = tuple.first; 
        result.second = tuple.second
     } else if ( result.second > tuple.first ) {

        // here you have overlapping number (tuple.first, min( result.second,tuple.second ))

        if ( result.second < tuple.second ) {
              result.second = tuple.second;
        }
     } else {
        result.second = tuple.second;
     }

 }
```

What we know, that if will be iterate next tuple first number is bigger or equals than result.first. Commentate in code tell you where you have overlapping and missing number

Comment: that will fail if T2 is a sub set of T1 and T3 overlaps with part of T1 that T2 does not. Where the number represents the order of which they are encountered

Comment: you are right, so first author's problem will be work fine, but second not.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var expandedSequences = sequences.Select(t => Enumerable.Range(t.Item1, t.Item2-t.Item1)).SelectMany(t => t).OrderBy(i => i);
var dupes = expandedSequences.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key);
var missing = Enumerable.Range(expandedSequences.Min(), expandedSequences.Max()).Except(expandedSequences);
```

Answer (score 1):

In one pass:

```
var sequences = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
    {
        new Tuple<int, int>(1, 10),
        new Tuple<int, int>(8, 101),
        new Tuple<int, int>(102, 103),
        new Tuple<int, int>(104, 104),
        new Tuple<int, int>(110, 200)
    };
var missing = new List<int>();
var overlap = new List<int>();

sequences.Aggregate((prev, current) => {
    if (prev.Item2 >= current.Item1) {
        overlap.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(current.Item1, prev.Item2 - current.Item1 + 1));
    }
    if (current.Item1 > prev.Item2 + 1) {
        missing.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(prev.Item2 + 1, current.Item1 - prev.Item2 - 1));
    }
    return current;
});
```

Comment: won't it fail if T2 is a sub set of T1 and T3 overlaps with part of T1 that T2 does not. Where the number represents the order of which they are encountered

Answer (score 1):

There's a few edge cases I can only assume how you wish to handle. I've chosen not to handle one of them (commented in the code). Since you've given no indication of how you would want to represent missing/ovrelapping sequences I've chosen your own format using tuples to identify the start and end of the sequence.

```
//Assumes they are sorted on item1
        Tuple<IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>>,IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>>> FindMissingAndOverLapping(IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> sequences){
            var previous = Tuple.Create(0, 0);
            var missing = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
            var overlapping = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            var max = 0;
            foreach (var sequence in sequences){
                var end = previous.Item2;
                max = end > max ? end : max;
                if (previous.Item2 < sequence.Item1 + 1){
                    missing.Add(Tuple.Create(previous.Item2 + 1, sequence.Item1 - 1));
                } else if (max < sequence.Item1){
                    overlapping.Add(Tuple.Create(sequence.Item1, max));
                }
            }
            //The sequences in ovrelapping can be ovrelapping them self
            return new Tuple<IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>>,IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>>>(missing, overlapping);
        }
```